# Combinatorial mini-game problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, problem-solving

In a win or lose game , the winner gets $2$ points whereas the loser gets $0$. *Six* players A, B, C, D, E and F play each other in a preliminary round from which the top *three* players move to the final round. After each player has played *four* games, A has $6$ points, B has $8$ points and C has $4$ points. It is also known the E won against F. In the next set of games D, E and F win their games against A, B and C respectively. If A, B and D move to the final round, what is the final score of E and F respectively?

**note**:I am completely new to such combinatorial problems so I request for a deep explanation of the essence of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: B has $8$ points (4 games), and did not play $E$. What does this tell about $A$ vs $B$? Now, do the same for $A$, and consider $A$ vs $C$. This will give you an account of all matches of $A,B,C$. Since $D$ moved to final round, prove that $D$ has 6 points in the end. What does this tell you about $D$ vs $E$ and $D$ vs $F$?

Comment: @DS There's a slightly simpler way. After 4 games, there are $4\times 3\times 2 = 24$ points, of which $6+8+4 = 18$ have been allocated to $A, B, C$. $D$ must have at least 4 points in order to move to the final round, and $E$ won against $F$ for the final 2 points.  $\quad$ Of course, this doesn't consider if such a tournament result could be achieved, which is what you are doing.

Comment: I had thought about summing up the points, but as soon as I noticed B won all matches till round 4, I solved it using the method in the comment. @CalvinLin